# How can I disable the focus ring in the firefox settings?

Tags: firefox, browser, accessibility

When an element is in focus, firefox automatically gives it a dotted outline, to show that the element is currently focused.
This can be really useful when navigating webpages with a keyboard and increases acessability a lot.

It however also looks rather ugly and when I am navigating the web using a Mouse, I would like it to not show up whatsoever.

There already are a lot of questions and answers on the web on how to disable these outlines using css, and the answer often is

```
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```

I would however like to disable this dotted outline everywere, not only on pages where I can edit the css, **preferrably by changing a simple browser setting.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the dotted outline that Firefox uses for keyboard focus without editing CSS or installing a browser extension.

Go to the browser's URL bar, type **`about:config`** and press Enter. This will open a page that warns you about changing advanced settings. Confirm the warning and then search for the setting "focus_ring_width". (Typing "focus" or "ring" into the search field should be sufficient to bring up a list of matching settings.)

Find the setting **`browser.display.focus_ring_width`** and set its value to 0. (The default is 1; setting a higher value makes the dotted outline thicker.) You can test the setting on a web page (in a different tab or window) before quitting the `about:config` settings.

Note that this only disables the browser's own focus indicator; it cannot disable style rules for `:focus` that are defined in the CSS that is linked to a webpages (but that is not what the question is about).

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. It keeps intended behavior on the focus ring while removing the visual distraction it causes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CSS on all pages by using [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

You may add this CSS by incorporating it in a Greasemonkey scriplet.

You may find more information on the [Greasemonkey site](https://www.greasespot.net/),
including [Tutorials](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Tutorials).

Comment: Is there no option to disable the accessibility features?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Well, I just think it is a little overkill to install a plugin like that to accomplish one small thing, I was just wondering if there was a flag to disable it.

Comment: I don't know of another way. Actually, there was a [bug reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=932410) 5 years ago when it stopped working, fixed since then.